# how does the google map api validate the key

Tags: api, google-maps, validation

If one want to use the google map api and its map data,he should register for a key for his website.

Now we want to open our own map api for other,so we require user who use our map api and map data register first.

However we have no idea how to validate.

FOr example, I have obtain a key of google map api,when I call the api,the js will downloaded to local,but I think there must be another validation when request map data from google.

how does they do?

Validte the site and key for each map tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use the third version of the api you won't need a key anymore :)

Comment: Thd main point is not whether google need a key. since we want to provide map-related api for others.and we want users who use our api must register for a key just like what google did before.

Answer (score 0):

They deprecated the key in v3. In v2 I'm assuming they matched your HTTP REFERER to the key that was assigned to your domain, and allowed the request if there was a match.